# Pulling first/last values from a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set of client sales over time. Few clients have the same date range, but I'm trying to create a chart that shows client-group growth over time.
My current thought is to number the months (1,2,3, etc) since the client began the program.

However, to do this I need a formula I can apply to a list several thousand clients long (and 10-15 dates per client) that will reset for each new client. Dates are in YYYY-MM format.
Any advice on how to create this? I'm stumped and it's 2AM. Also very open to alternatives.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your data set?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/iOQ1QZ5

Comment: There is definitely some further clarification required here because based on the screenshots, it looks like you have your solution. Between the 2 images, where exactly is your issue? You may just have to find another way to describe your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not a whole lot to go on here, but this sounds like it could be done in a pivot table.  If you are trying to avoid a pivot table, you can try formulas countif or sumif to capture the client and count or sum whatever you are trying to capture.  Your date, if it is in a text format, should be converted to an excel date, =date(value(left(G5,4)),value(right(G5,2)),1).

Comment: Thank you, but there's several thousand clients. That didn't end up working. unless I'm missing something obvious. https://imgur.com/a/iOQ1QZ5 
I'm not sure how I can convert this into first month in the program, second month in the program, etc from what it is now.